# How do I add parameters to a link_to external URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Show User page, I want to add a link to an external website with some values saved in the table passed as parameters.

I got the first part working right, that's simple.

```
<%= link_to "Outside Site", "http://outsidesite.com/create" %>
```

But I also want to pass some paramaters which are saved in the database, like `@user.email`, `@user.first_name`, etc.

So basically the final link will look like:

http://outsidesite.com/create?email=user@email.com&firstname=userfirstname etc etc.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because rails don't know how the website want it's paramteres, I think you must do it with string concatenation. At least, you can write a helper to do this for you but will just become a string concatenation in the end.

Comment: I figured out how to do it myself, less than 10 minutes later haha.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem, what method did you use? Write you answer here and mark it as correct in 2 days so it can be used as a reference for future developers

Comment: Yeah I was planning to do that :) I just went with `<%= link_to "Outside Site", ('http://outsidesite.com?email='+@user.email+'&firstname='+@user.firstname) %>` and adding whatever else I need. I'm not missing anything am I?

Comment: No that's exactly what I wrote in my answer: string concatenation

Comment: For performance reasons you want to do interpolation (as @kasrak mentioned) instead of concatenation, see: http://blog.purepistos.net/index.php/2008/07/14/benchmarking-ruby-string-interpolation-concatenation-and-appending/

Comment: I think (I am not sure) he is using concatenation because rails is automagically calling URI.escape on all function concatenated in that string. I'm **definitely** not sure of it.

Answer (score 6):

You can write the helper method such as url patern. You can check the code bellow:

```
  def generate_url(url, params = {})
    uri = URI(url)
    uri.query = params.to_query
    uri.to_s
  end
```

After that, you can call the helper method like:

```
generate_url("YOUR-URL-ADDR-HERE", :param1 => "first", :param2 => "second")
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: I you also want to keep original params you can use concatenation: `uri.query = (uri.query || "").concat(params.to_query)`

Answer (score 4):

This is a valid approach:

```
<% = link_to "Outside Site", 
"http://outsidesite.com/create?email=#{@user.email}" %>
```

Just make sure you escape the variables you're putting into the URL:

```
require 'uri'
escaped_email = URI.escape(@user.email)
```

Comment: Thanks. I found a way to do it without having to escape the variables.

Answer (score -2):

Give this a try

```
# routes.rb
get 'create?:query' => 'users#create', :as => :create_users_with_query

# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_params
    "email=#{self.email}&firstname=#{self.firstname}"
  end
end

# view
<%= link_to "Outside Site", create_users_with_query(@user) %>
```